# Is it ok to title a narrow table column Z. instead of Anz.?

Tags: abbreviation

Looking for abbreviations to replace the word Anz. (for Anzahl), owing to a lack of tabular space, I came across the abbreviation Z. for Zahl on these websites:

http://www.abbreviations.com/Z
http://www.dw.com/en/best-german-abbreviations-from-aa-to-zz/g-18791484

Does Zahl mean the same as Anzahl?
More specifically, would a very narrow table column titled Z. explain the same information as a column titled Anz.?

Comment: I have never seen *Z* as abbreviation in that context, "No" for "Nummero" coming closest, but this more corresponds to an incrementing counter. I'd propose to use the somewhat international symbol # instead.

Comment: Does this column contain a consecutive number (of the row) or any number of things in this row?

Comment: Another possibility can be to use *n*, which is regularly used to denote a number in mathematical or scientific contexts.

Comment: @IQV No. jonathan.scholbach, n sounds like English doesn't it?

Comment: @guidot # sounds like its being tallied or given a no. It is derived and is formed through different groups.U might, but groups won't understand "#".

Answer (score 5):

## [*n*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anzahl)

I would not recommend to use `Z` as an abbreviation for German *Anzahl* it will likely not be understood.

In a scientific context, and also in school maths or physics we also do use the international symbol [*n*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anzahl) (or upper case `N`) for *Anzahl*. In German this would then not be derived from the English *number* but from Latin *numero* (in case you are concerned about this).

Comment: Maybe even use **N**, because **n** could be misinterpreted as an index sometimes. Really depends on the table in question, though.

Comment: @Chieron: thanks, edited into the answer.

Comment: @Chieron indices more often get abbreviated as **i**.

Comment: @Takkat Doesn't "N" mainly suit a column describing numbers in scientific, legal or political domains, because it is a Latin term?
The context for the Anz. column does not lie in these domains.

Comment: @user25590: basically you are free to use any letter as long as you explain it somewhere. From all letters it is the *n* that would likely be recognized by most people as standing for a number.